# Screen obscured after minimizing Genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I have been having a problem with my virtual devices in Genymotion. Whenever I start a virtual device, it starts fine and I can use it, but if I minimize the window and try to use it again the screen gets obscured, and shows whatever is behind it. The effect can be seen in this screenshot:
[image]

This happens when I start the virtual device using the Genymotion application or when using the Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've already found out, but to view the screen again, it is enough to press a button on the right (e.g. Vol +/-), or swipe with the mouse.
I know it is a workaround, but I've already got used to doing it each time

Comment: Thanks, I never noticed this. I should note that only some of the buttons seem to fix this for me, vol does nothing for instance, but if I click recent apps the screen appears.